# Exit code for ldap testing using nc or ncat

Tags: ldap, shell, shell-scripting, nc

I am trying to write shell script to test if a server is able to reach a specified ip and port.

The commands i am using: `ncat -w 5 <IP> 636 or 389 > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null | echo $?`
The issue is when i check for an exit code for the above two ports i receive a 1.

When i run it without the /dev/null I get an connected to ip.
`ncat -v -w 5 <IP> 636
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to <IP>:636.
^C`

The issue is if i use the second command without /dev/null, i need to manually cancel the command using: `CTRL + C`

Any suggestions on how can i test the ip and ldap port using ncat or nc?

Comment: BTW forgot to mention the ncat version: `ncat --version
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-z` flag. If it has it.

```
-z      Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without
        sending any data to them.  It is an error to use this option in
        conjunction with the -l option.
```

So try this

```
ncat -z -w 5 <IP> 636
```

Comment: I try that command: `nc -z -w 5 <IP> 636
nc: invalid option -- 'z'
Ncat: Try '--help' or man(1) ncat for more information, usage options and help. QUITTING.`

Comment: I believe the -z option was included in a later ncat version, I might be using an older ncat as mention above in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Piping makes no sense here.  Use `; echo $?` not `| echo $?`.

```
2. Shell Command Language
[...]
2.9.2 Pipelines
[...]
the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02